# In win32 programming, how do I CreateWindowEx that doesn't appear in taskbar and in alt+tab list?

Tags: windows, winapi

What window styles do I pass to `CreateWindowEx` so that the window doesn't appear in taskbar and in alt+tab list?

I'm passing `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`, which achieves but the window I'm creating is not really a "tool window".

Comment: The question [How to hide window from "Applications" tab in task manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682823/how-to-hide-window-from-applications-tab-in-task-manager) shows how to hide from Alt+Tab and the taskbar. (The OP wanted to know how to hide from Applications, but the answer to your question is in that other question.)

Answer (score 3):

The MSDN lists two possible solutions at [The Taskbar - Managing Taskbar Buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179.aspx#Managing_Taskbar_But):

> To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the **`WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`** extended style. As an alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible window.

Note that when implementing the alternative solution to set up the windows as *owner* and *owned* window (as opposed to *parent* and *child* window). In other words, the owned window must not contain the `WS_CHILD` window style.